# TraversableOnce MonadOps in Scala collection library

Tags: scala, collections, traversable

I'm looking at Scala 2.12 Collection Library sources and noticed the following thing:

```
trait TraversableOnce[+A] extends Any with GenTraversableOnce[A] {

  //methods

  implicit class MonadOps[+A](trav: TraversableOnce[A]) {
    def map[B](f: A => B): TraversableOnce[B] = trav.toIterator map f
    def flatMap[B](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B]): TraversableOnce[B] = trav.toIterator flatMap f
    def withFilter(p: A => Boolean) = trav.toIterator filter p
    def filter(p: A => Boolean): TraversableOnce[A] = withFilter(p)
  }
}
```

What is the reason the Monad Ops are put into `implicit` class? The `Traversable` subtrait of `TraversableOnce` has this all monadic methods defined not as imlpicit class (through `TraversableLike` though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Iterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Iterator.html), as something we only expect to traverse once, is an example of something that extends `TraversableOnce` without extending `Traversable`. The methods on `MonadOps` will be used there.

Note `MonadOps` is in the companion object, not the trait.

Also note `TraversableOnce` has been deprecated in 2.13.0 in favour of `IterableOnce`.